# elasticsearch nested aggregation sorting

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have trouble sorting nested aggregations in elasticsearch, for example:

```
"traits_agg": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "traits"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "traits_name_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "traits.name",
        "size": 100000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "traits_value_agg": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "traits.value",
            "size": 100000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a buckets in the response like:

```
      {
        "key": "Special",
        "doc_count": 20,
        "traits_value_agg": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "Earth",
              "doc_count": 6
            },
            {
              "key": "Fire",
              "doc_count": 5
            },
            {
              "key": "Sakura",
              "doc_count": 5
            },
            {
              "key": "Water",
              "doc_count": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

how does one sort by the main bucket "key", so that "Special" is towards the end of the bucket lists

Comment: what criteria are you thinking of to have "Special" towards the end? number of documents or alphabetical?

Comment: the default one is number of documents right? alphabetically or a custom field from within the nested doc